# Backbone routing after login modal

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone application with lot of views such as:
Home
my profile
marketplace
.....

I have a login view in this web page application. When a user clicks on my profile, I want them to go to **login view** and then to **my profile**. How can I do that?

I can route to one location but I dont know if there is a call back function?

How can I combine these two router function to run one after another?

```
Router.navigate('login', true);

Router.navigate('myprofile', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you

```
routes: {
 // Pages
 'myprofile':'myprofile'
}
-------------------------------------------
router.on('route:myprofile', function (actions) {
   //check if user is logged in let it remain at myprofile else;
   Router.navigate('login', true);
})
```

Thanks,

Dhiraj